# How to include two resources in Page.Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF, this used to work fine:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />
</Page.Resources>
```

but adding a converter (see below) causes an error on the 2nd resource (`Style.xaml`): `Each dictionary entry must have an associated key`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MySizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />
</Page.Resources>
```

However, adding a key to the 2nd line (e.g. `<ResourceDictionary x:Key="myStyleDict" Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />` causes the following error in code behind

```
The name 'aTextBlockUsedToWork' does not exist in the current context
```

where `aTextBlockUsedToWork` could be successfully accessed in code behind before adding the key. Note that the converter works fine if I comment out the style resource. How can I have both of the resources working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `MergedDictionaries` to import another dictionary file, like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:MySizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: thanks! do you know any good tutorials on using ResourceDictionary and good practice to group/"modulize" resources (such as Styles, DatasTemplates, etc.)? I am new to this and all the examples I saw seem to suggest one can define and use Resources anywhere. just wondering if there is some good practice to follow. thanks again!

Comment: Here are two: `http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx` & `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35346/Using-a-Resource-Dictionary-in-WPF`